# SQL: auto_increment of primary key counts different since I added unique keys?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, insert-update, unique-key, on-duplicate-key

Today I added two unique keys (`external_id`, `name`) to my table. Since then the counting of the `id`-column (primary key) is very weird and I'm not able to reproduce the issue.

I didn't delete any row, but I updated (`ON DUPLICATE KEY`). I'd like the primary key `id` to be counted up linear, like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

**Structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `external_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `external_id` (`external_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

**Content:**

```
ID  | external_id | name | x | y | z
------------------------------------
  1 |          1  | A    | 3 | 3 | 2
  2 |          2  | B    | 2 | 2 | 5
  7 |          3  | C    | 5 | 3 | 2
 11 |          1  | D    | 7 | 6 | 3
 12 |          2  | E    | 5 | 4 | 2
 17 |          3  | F    | 3 | 8 | 5
 21 |          1  | G    | 6 | 6 | 3
 22 |          2  | H    | 8 | 5 | 7
 23 |          3  | I    | 1 | 0 | 9
```

**Edit:**
The latest ID is `23`. In the *row statistics* of PHPMyAdmin the *next autoindex* is announced as `27`! What about 24 to 26? I'm confused.

Is there any wrong in the structure or a secret I haven't heard of? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible that they are just being displayed in a different order because you didn't specify ORDER BY? Try: SELECT * FROM table_test ORDER BY id;

Comment: @sqlvogel no, it's not possible - unfortunately. The table above is an exact copy from phpmyadmin and ordered by id already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies. Finally I found the error. That's how the structure should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `external_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `x` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `y` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `z` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`external_id`,`name`) # ----- this line was changed
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have removed data from the table, the id values that have already been used will not be used again.  So if you have:

```
ID  | external_id | name | x | y | z
------------------------------------
  1 |          1  | A    | 3 | 3 | 2
  2 |          2  | B    | 2 | 2 | 5
  3 |          3  | C    | 5 | 3 | 2
  4 |          1  | D    | 2 | 2 | 5
  5 |          2  | E    | 5 | 3 | 2
  6 |          3  | F    | 5 | 3 | 2
```

and then delete rows 3 - 6 and add more data, the id will start incrementing at 7 the next time around.

Comment: As I already mentioned: I didn't delete any row. That's the point. ;(

Comment: My apologies. I missed that statement

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic Have you attempted to drop the table and create it again?

Comment: yes, of course but there was an error in my structure. take a look at the answer. thanks for your comment!